# Insert into with condition

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm working with python and using pymysql library and i want to write a query that insert an array in a line where a column has some special value.
For example insert 'hi' into a column where user_id is 22
for that query i write this code 
    from pymysql import *
    chat_id = 22
    user_first_name = "hi"

```
db = connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", passwd="", 
db='support',charset='utf8')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO users user_firstname VALUE %s WHERE user_id is 
%s""",(user_first_name, chat_id))
db.commit()
```

how should i write this query in correct form?

Comment: Where is the column `user_id`? If it's in a row of `users`? Because in that case, what you need is an UPDATE (you don't need to add records, you have to modify them)

Comment: yes user_id column is in the users table.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm undertanding, correctly, rather than an `INSERT INTO`, it seems you need an `UPDATE`:

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE users SET user_firstname='%s' WHERE user_id=%s""",(user_first_name, chat_id))
```

Comment: no it's not in this way it gives error like this :
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user_id=322434411' at line 1"

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Francisco is right though. If you have a user_id already, then an UPDATE should be used to change the value of and existing record. The INSERT command, creates a new record.